# Why HTTP Error code start from 100

Tags: http, standards, http-status-codes, specifications

While working on recent REST apis I had a question that why "IANA" decided to have HTTP status code from 100 only and not from 1. I hope there will be a reason behind it but I am curious to know about that.

Comment: I doubt you can get an authoritative answer for such kind of questions from a community; better is to ask the standard authors directly. All we can do is to guess using first found coffee grounds. But personally to me it's connected with the main approach to make a human friendly protocol. For HTTP this includes loose grammar with free formatting (except some simple rules), arbitrary spaces, case sensitive matching, and so on. With this main principle, it's incorrect to require writing 001 but not 1. OTOH variable length values are worse looking. But tastes are different and unpredictable.

Comment: IANA just maintains the registry. The ranges are defined by the IETF spec.

Comment: @Netch Below categorization of status code makes sense for having three digit status codes.

Comment: I agree with the comment by user:Netch. My guess (out of the blue) is that the motivation was to avoid the specification of how to handle formatting of possibly leading zeroes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP/1.0 added status codes to HTTP/0.9, the initially released version. The status code range is defined as such:

> [**RFC 1954, 6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-6.1.1)

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
> attempt to understand and satisfy the request[...]. The
> Status-Code is intended for use by automata[...].

> The first digit of the Status-Code defines the class of response. The last two digits do not have any categorization role. There are 5 values for the first digit:

> - 1xx: Informational - Not used, but reserved for future use

> - 2xx: Success - The action was successfully received, understood, and accepted.

> - 3xx: Redirection - Further action must be taken in order to complete the request

> - 4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled

> - 5xx: Server Error - The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request

As for the "why": it allows for five categories, each of which can contain a hundred different codes (x00 - x99), which "ought to be enough for anybody".

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster yes above details makes sense. So we do have 100 different codes in each category and five categories at this moment to describe the status. Though it looks like 100 status are enough at this moment hope we don't run out of status codes in any categories. :D

Comment: But they could use same tactic as Windows/Linux uses: 0 to ... Ex.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: But why did it start at 100? Couldn't 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 be enough? Or 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. Who decides which numbers get picked up? And also, why is class 2 a success instead of say 1?

Comment: @piepi you'd have to ask Sir Tim Berners-Lee.

Answer (score 2):

The status codes are not numbered in a consecutive manner. The first digit indicates the type of status code, e.g. 2xx for success and 4xx for client error. The last to digits are used to specify the status code more. Two digits are needed because more then 9 status codes per type exists.

Comment: If there are more than 9 status codes per type, then couldn't they have assigned more than one digit at tens place for each type of code?

Comment: @ankit Sound less convenient to me.